# How do pointers to pointers and the address-of operator work?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

Take this piece of code:

```
int a;
int *pointer = &a;

int **b = &(&(*pointer));
```

Would the above set `b` to the address of `pointer` or not?

The reason I ask is because `*pointer` gives the value of `a`, and the reference of that is the address of `a`. Is this treated as just the address of `a`, or is it also treated as `pointer`.

Does this make sense? Could I do:

```
&(*pointer) = a;
```

Comment: `b = &pointer` is the correct way to get the address of the pointer to `a`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. In C, you can only get a pointer to a storage area (which means a variable, an array element, or another pointer; they call those "l-values"), not to any expression. You cannot get a pointer to an expressions that has no defined storage area (like an addition, or the result of a function call). It should be noted however that C++ messes these rules with references, but for the sake of clarity, I'll leave it out.

Pointers aren't magical: in the end, they're just integers. Therefore, when you get the pointer of a pointer, it's just like you were getting the pointer of an integer. It has no more repercussions.

For instance, if you get the pointer to `a` in your code, you're just copying this address in another variable. Nothing keeps you from changing said variable:

```
int a;
int* p = &a;
p = NULL;
```

And doing this, you `a` will remain unaltered. All you can change about `a` is its value. Its address is immutable. Anything else would imply that `&a = NULL` (or any other pointer value) would work, which doesn't.

Comment: Thankyou, I understand how pointer work. I just wanted to confirm that &(*pointer) was an rvalue.

Comment: @Alexander Rafferty Actually, GCC will let you do it. It will however emit a deprecation warning stating that `&(*pointer)` is not really an l-value and that it will stop working somewhere in the future, so you shouldn't do it anyways. Clang will emit a hard error. I don't know what Visual Studio will say, but it will probably emit a hard error too.

Comment: "If you can't do it, then you can't get a pointer to it." is wrong. Arrays and const variables are a couple exceptions.

Comment: @R.. Yeah, I removed that part.

Answer (score 3):

> int **b = &(&(*pointer));

This doesn't, or shouldn't compile.

You can only take the address of an l-value.  (See below for a description)

**C++03 S5.3.1-2:**

> The result of the unary & operator is
>   a pointer to its operand. The operand
>   shall be an lvalue or a qualifiedid.
>   In the first case, if the type of the
>   expression is “T,” the type of the
>   result is “pointer to T.” In
>   particular, the address of an object
>   of type “cv T” is “pointer to cv T,”
>   with the same cv-qualifiers. For a
>   qualified-id, if the member is a
>   static member of type “T”, the type of
>   the result is plain “pointer to T.” If
>   the member is a nonstatic member of
>   class C of type T, the type of the
>   result is “pointer to member of class
>   C of type

---

> ...and the reference of that is the address of a...

Also you are using the term reference wrong here.  & is a symbol that is used for different things.  one of those things is to declare references, an unrelated thing is the address of unary operator.  The later is not called a reference.

---

> Does this make sense? Could I do: `&(*pointer) = a;`

An address of a variable, and hence `&(*pointer)` or equivalently `&a` are r-values.

You can't assign anything to an r-avlue.  Ignoring things like const you can consider an r-value something that must appear on the right hand side.  An l-value is kind of like left hand side but really it means it can be stored in a storage location (the difference is because a const object for example can't appear on the left hand side but it is still considered an l-value).

Answer (score 1):

You can't take the address of something twice, so the above code probably won't even compile (have you tried that? What happened?).

Comment: When I tried it, gcc says `warning: argument to '&' not really an lvalue; this will be a hard error in the future` but `**b` gives the value of `a`.

Comment: @jleedev: That sounds like you have a pretty old version of gcc. What are you using?

Comment: @Brian That was with Apple’s version of gcc 4.2.1. On Debian (gcc 4.3.2) and OpenBSD (gcc 3.3.5), I get the expected `error: invalid lvalue in unary '&'`. A quick search makes me suspect Apple added that warning.

Answer (score 0):

In your expression:

*ptr is a lvalue
&(*ptr) is a rvalue

&(&(*ptr)) is an ill-formed expression as you are trying to take the address of an rvalue which is not allowed in C++.

Furthermore,

&(*pointer) = a;

is ill-formed, because the type of the lhs expression is 'int *' where type of rhs expression is 'int'. C++ does not allow converting an 'int' to 'int *'

Answer (score 0):

> Would the above set b to the address of pointer or not?

No, it won't. `&(*pointer)` is the address of `a`, which is just a number (an r-value), and you can't take the address of or assign to an r-value. So both `&(&(*pointer))` and `&(*pointer) = a` will not compile.

The address of `pointer` is simply `&pointer`, so what *will* work is `int **b = &pointer;`.

Answer (score 0):

1.No, and that make compile error at `int **b = &(&(*pointer));` 
2.Set b to the address of pointer: `int **b = &pointer;`
3.`&(*pointer) = a;`  -> NO you cant. `&something` is constant cant be changed, must be `*pointer = a;` or `pointer = &a;`